# Django rest Framework django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'files'

Tags: python-3.x, rest, file-upload, django-rest-framework

I am trying to upload the image using the api but this error is displayed.
can anyone please tell me what is the problem.

```
Method Not Allowed: /scanner/batch-upload/
[09/Nov/2021 00:44:03] "GET /scanner/batch-upload/ HTTP/1.1" 405 8763
Internal Server Error: /scanner/batch-upload/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/py_speedy_scanner_img2pdf/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 78, in __getitem__
    list_ = super().__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'files'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/py_speedy_scanner_img2pdf/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/py_speedy_scanner_img2pdf/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/py_speedy_scanner_img2pdf/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/py_speedy_scanner_img2pdf/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/py_speedy_scanner_img2pdf/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/py_speedy_scanner_img2pdf/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/py_speedy_scanner_img2pdf/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/py_speedy_scanner_img2pdf/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/py_speedy_scanner_img2pdf/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/py_speedy_scanner_img2pdf/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 190, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/py_speedy_scanner_img2pdf/accounts/views.py", line 336, in create
    file_path = request.FILES['files'].read()
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/py_speedy_scanner_img2pdf/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 80, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'files'
[09/Nov/2021 00:44:07] "POST /scanner/batch-upload/ HTTP/1.1" 500 110792
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because cannot find the file key in the request.Post .

Python dictionaries have an integrated static method .get() . When .get() cannot find a key, it returns the default None value or the value you specified.

I suggest using .get() . Here is an example.

Change the settings of the program

```
request.POST[""]
```

to

```
request.POST.get("", "default value")
```

In addition, there is no need to write {% csrf_token %} before each input field. For each form only one csrf_token is required. Thus, you can remove others, just store one inside the form tag.